# how to do the update function according to the ID in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie in Codeigniter. I want to update the data according to the id.
Here is my controller:

```
> public function Edit($Course_ID=0)
>      {
>          $this->load->model('CourseRecord');
>          $this->load->helper('form');
>          
>          /* Session */
>          $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
>          $data['User_Name'] = $session_data['User_Name'];
>          $this->session->set_userdata($data);
>          
>          /* Form Validation*/
>          
>          /* Get Record */
>          $data['query'] = $this->CourseRecord->view($Course_ID);
>          /* View*/
>          $this->load->view('templates/header');
>          $this->load->view('Course_Edit',$data);
>          $this->load->view('templates/footer');
> 
>          $my_action = $this->input->post('submit');
>              if ($my_action == 'submit') 
>              {
>                  $this->CourseRecord->update($Course_ID);
>              }
>          
>     }
```

here is my model:

```
> function update($Course_ID)
>     {
>         $data = array(
>             'Course_Code' => $this->input->post('Course_Code'),
>             'Course_Name' => $this->input->post('Course_Name'),
>             'Semester' => $this->input->post('Semester'),
>             'Session' => $this->input->post('Session'),
>             'Course_Type' => $this->input->post('Course_Type'),
>             'Credit_Hours' => $this->input->post('Credit_Hours'),
>             'Course_Ins' => $this->input->post('Course_Ins'),
>             'Assess_Start_Date' => $this->input->post('Assess_Start_Date'),
>             'Assess_Finish_Date' => $this->input->post('Assess_Finish_Date'),
>             'Total_Student' => $this->input->post('Total_Student')
>                 
>                 );
>         $this->db->where('Course_ID',$Course_ID);
>         $this->db->update('course_detail',$data);
>     }
```

The problem is at the controller where it unable to recognise `$Course_ID` at the `$this->CourseRecord->update($Course_ID);` .If I change the `$Course_ID` to the ID number(for example, `$Course_ID=1`),I function well.
Hope some one can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

if you passing your Course_ID from url then you have change your $Course_ID=0 to $Course_ID=null because i think this problem create by this $Course_ID=0 it always take $Course_ID to zero

Comment: Thank you for reply.same problem,unable to update the data.i think the problem is in the if...else statement where the $Course_ID unable to get the data.I had tried to replace the $Course_ID with the actual ID value,and it functionally well.

Comment: then try this $this->form_validation->set_rules('submit', 'submit', 'required');if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
             {  $this->CourseRecord->update($Course_ID); }

Comment: The $Course_ID inside if...else statement still unable to get the value.So,it unable to update the data.Is there any solutions that can be used to declare the value of $Course_ID before it can be used in the if...else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your Edit Function $Course_Id=" "

> public function Edit($Course_ID=" ")
>     {
>
> ```
>   $data['action'] = site_url('controllername/update/'.$Course_ID);
>  //pass this action in view page as <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>"> </form>
>  //so on submit of your Code you will Get All Post Data in update(Course_ID='') method  
>
>  //Your Code goes Here Upto View.
> ```
>
> }
>
> public function update($Course_Id="")
>   {
>
> ```
> // here you will get your all Post data with Course_Id.
> // and then update your data with your Model code..
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Thank you for reply.ya,I can get the value but it unable to bring the value into the if...else statement.so,it unable to update the data...

Comment: you are Not getting Course_Id in IF..else stmt..because your View is Loaded First so that's why you are not getting It In iF--else stmt..

Answer (score 0):

this is my view before enter to the edit function in the controller.

```
> <?php foreach ($query as $row):?>
>                 <tr>
>                     <td><?php echo $row->Course_ID;?></td>
>                     <td><?php echo $row->Course_Code;?></td>
>                     <td><?php echo $row->Course_Name;?></td>
>                     <td><?php echo $row->Semester;?></td>
>                     <td><?php echo $row->Session;?></td>
>                     <td><?php echo $row->Course_Ins;?></td>
>                     <td><?php echo anchor('Course_Record/View/'.$row->Course_ID,'View') ;?></td>
>                     <td><?php echo anchor('Course_Record/Edit/'.$row->Course_ID,'Edit',
> 'Course_ID="Course_ID"') ;?></td>
>                     <td><?php echo anchor('Course_Record/Delete/'.$row->Course_ID,'Delete',
> 'Course_ID="Course_ID"') ;?></td>
>                 </tr>
>                 <?php endforeach;?>
```

then the controller will pass the data to the view with the name Course_Edit.here is some of the code...

```
> <fieldset>        
>      <legend><b>Course Detail</b></legend>
>          <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
>      
>          <?php echo form_open('Course_Record/Edit') ?>
>              <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" size="80%">
>                  <tr>
>                      <td>
>                          <table border="1" wcellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
>                              <tr>
>                                  <td colspan="4"><p>&nbsp;</p><u>Course Info</u></td>
>                              </tr>
>                              
>                              <tr>
>                                  <td> Course_ID</td>
>                                  <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Course_ID"  disabled="disable" value="<?php echo
> $query->Course_ID; ?>"/>
>                              </tr> <tr>
>                                  <td>Course Code :</td>
>                                  <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Course_Code" id="Course_Code"  value="<?php echo
> $query->Course_Code; ?>"/>
>                              </tr>
>                              
>                              <tr>
>                                  <td>Course Name :</td>
>                                  <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Course Name" id="Course_Name"  value="<?php echo
> $query->Course_Name; ?>"/>
>                              </tr>
```

really hope someone can help me.I am newbie in codeigniter.thanks